# IOS upload image success but upload failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been looking examples for the new AFNetworking 2.0 to upload images. But the pictures I upload always failed. So this is the code I used

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *imagetes = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.picprofile.image = imagetes;

    NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[refURL] options:nil];
    NSString *filename = [[result firstObject] filename];
    NSLog(@"FileName == %@", filename);

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"do":@"profile",@"what":@"editFoto",@"session":sesion};
    NSString *URLString = BaseURLString;

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.picprofile.image, 0.5); // image size ca. 50 KB
    NSLog(@"imageData == %@", imageData);
    [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:120];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"foto" fileName:filename mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure %@, %@", error, operation.responseString);
    }];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting in response?

Comment: @Shabirjan response success, but failed image uploaded to the server

Comment: Your upload looks OK. `UIImage` > JPEG `NSData` > Form upload. I'm guessing this is something server sided. (Moving the file from /tmp, upload permissions, `max_upload_filesize`, etc...)

Comment: How does it actually "fail"? Do you have an error message somewhere? Have you checked server logs?

Comment: @jcaron The following is a response from the server that I show of responseObject  logs  "code = 200 Success {
    status = fail;
}"

Comment: Is it your own server or are you using a public API? If the former, include your server-side code and logs. If the latter, please share specifications or tell us what service you're using if the docs are public.

Comment: @jcaron I use my own server,what do you mean this? <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15f13f960> { URL: http://api.xxxxx.com/ } { status code: 200, headers {
    "CF-RAY" = "3220107d63f93072-SIN";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 16 Jan 2017 08:05:47 GMT";
    Server = "cloudflare-nginx";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
}

Comment: No, I mean the code of the service that is called by your app, and the logs on the server when you make a request to that service using your app (the request that fails).

Comment: @jcaron whether this what you mean? debug =     (
                (
                        (
                "SELECT \"id_user\" FROM \"t_session\" WHERE \"code_session\" = '5fcdcdb6d5645c0eaf93e7e12f6f5789' LIMIT 1",
                Success
            )
        )
    );
    message = "not find photo";
    status = fail;

Comment: That seems to be a bit of the logs of the server, still missing the relevant source code, but those logs alone should help you find where the issue is: "not find photo" seems to be a big hint...